# How to run a Windows command from any folder?

Tags: command-line, redis, command-line-interface, redis-cli

Some CLI commands work from only specific folders; I want to make them run globally, from anywhere.

I installed `redis-cli.exe` in the path `c:/redis/redis-cli.exe`.
Now when I open a cmd in `c:/redis/` and run `redis-cli ping`, it works.
However, if I run it from some other folder, it throws an error saying
`'redis-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

In contrast, `Chocolatey` or `npm` runs from a cmd console opened in any folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Add the path to that exe in your environment variables.

So for `c:/redis/redis-cli.exe`, add the value `c:/redis` to PATH in your environment variables.